# How does SVM classify when test data point lies between the 2 margins

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I have understood that SVM classifies points using a hyperplane and a margin. A point is classified +ve when `w.x + b >= 1` (margin 1) and -ve when `w.x + b <= -1` (margin 2) and the decision boundary has equation as `w.x + b = 0`. I still don't understand, how would SVM classify a point coming from test data which lies in between the margin?

Comment: it always uses $wx + b = 0$ to do classification (i.e., if $wx + b > 0$ then class A, else class B). The soft margin concept just applies for training, i.e., the algorithm tolerates some missclassification during the training stage.

Comment: @Zhanxiong So you mean to say that $wx+b>=1$ and $wx+b<=1$ is only used while training the model and classification on test data is done using $wx+b>=0$ or $wx+b<0$ conditions. Right?

Comment: That's right. Also, if you review the math details in SVM training, I don't think it's necessary to introduce the plane $wx + b = \pm 1$ explicitly. It is the *slack variable* $\xi_n = |t_n - (wx_n + b)| \geq 0$ that enters the optimization formulation. Of course, on the decision plane, $\xi_n = 1$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I think you can convert your comment to an answer

Comment: @gunes I am happy to do that when I get time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Zhanxiong's comment as an answer.

THE SVM always uses `wx+b=0` to do classification (i.e., if `wx+b>0` then class A, else class B). The soft margin concept just applies for training, i.e., the algorithm tolerates some misclassification during the training stage.

This means that `wx+b>=1` and `wx+b<=1` is only used while training the model and classification on test data is done using `wx+b>=0` or `wx+b<0` conditions.